# How to find Page state is changed or not in ASP.NET AJAX or Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have ASP.NET web application. Which is having some pages. In one of the pages I have search filters

with 10 Text-boxes. Here, whenever user enters some values in any one of the Text-boxes and clicks

Search button, request will go to server and brings results accordingly. Even if the user does NOT

change any thing in text boxes  and clicks again search button, I need to post-back unnecessarily.

How can I prevent this unnecessary post back?

How to  find is there any changes happened in page using Ajax or Java Script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to check fields changes

```
var allowPostback  = false;

$( "input[type='text']" ).change(function() {
        allowPostback = true;
    });
```

And on you "Search" button click

```
<asp:button runat="server".... OnClientClick="return allowPostback;" />
```

Comment: I don't want to do like that.If I have drop down list again I need to write separate code.If I add any new text box or some other control I need to change code again...

Comment: No you don't. You can add some common class to all controls yup wan't to track and change selector from input[type=text ] to $('.myclass').change...

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too.

[How to detect HTML form changes?](http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-html-form-changes/)